# ContinueWith is invoked with faulted readasstringasync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am sending a JSON request of size 6MB to my Web API where I am using `ReadAsStringAsync` method to get the request in string format. I have added `ContinueWith` to do some post processing.

Below is the code.

```
myRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(t => 
{
    //Post Processing
});
```

But when I checked "`t`", it's in faulted state and it has

> "Error while copying content to a stream"

exception.

I am getting this issue intermittently; not always. However, if I change this from asynchronous to synchronous, it's working fine.

Is this happening because of memory or some other issue?

Comment: Have you called `ReadAsStreamAsync` on the same `Content` somewhere?

Comment: No, I have not called ReadAsStreamAsync anywhere in my application

Comment: Can you post the code that surrounds this, so we can see the context for how this is being invoked?

Comment: `public class HandlerClass : DelegatingHandler
{
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage myRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
  myRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
  {
   // Log request in database
  }
  return base.SendAsync(myRequest, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t =>
  {
   //Request Processing
  }
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Based on example provided, `SendAsync` returns a `Task` which means that it can be made async.

Consider making the function async so that calls can be awaited and invoked in a synchronous manner.

```
public class HandlerClass : DelegatingHandler { 
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) { 

        var data = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Log request in database

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // Response Processing 

        return response;
    } 
}
```